# Entity Framework: Filtering navigation-property data

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, lazy-loading

I am struggling with ASPs MVC model / entity framework. I am quite new so this is largely the problem. I have 3 database tables that are linked together:

- Project
- Stages
- Compfiles

Each stage is linked to one project (in `Project` table) and hundreds of files in the `Compfiles` table.

I am trying to build a report that will show all Stages & Computer files for a given project number (`PrjNo`).

I am populating my model using this code:

```
    var stageFiles = db.Stages.Where(c => c.PrjNo == PrjNo)
    .Include(c => c.Project)
    .Include(c => c.Compfiles);

    return View(stageFiles.ToList());
```

The table `Compfiles` has a column `IsLatest` and I only want to show results where `IsLatest = 1`.

How can I filter the `.Include(c => c.Compfiles)` bit based on what is in `c.Compfiles`?

Comment: Try .Include(c => c.Compfiles).Where(x=>x.IsLatest==1);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Framework doesn't support criteria-based `Include()`, once you're including some navigation property, the entire (related) data will be fetched from the database.

You also need to realize that `Include()` is only meant to instruct EF to *pre-fetch* the related data, it has nothing to do with the query criteria.

However, you can easily mitigate the problem if you'll create a custom type that will wrap all your necessary (report) fields then use projection to fetch only the relevant data. For example:

```
public class StageReportData
{
    // Stage primary-key
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // More Stage data that is needed for the report
    // ...

    public Project Project { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Compfile> Compfiles { get; set; }
}
```

Then when querying EF:

```
var stageFiles = db.Stages
                   .Where(c => c.PrjNo == PrjNo)
                   .Select(x => new StageReportData
                       {
                       Id = x.Id,
                       Project = x.Project,
                       Compfiles = x.Compfiles.Where(c => c.IsLatest == 1)
                       });
```

More on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh205756.aspx)